# Map MessageBox Ok to keyboard button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an application that works with touch screen and am using hardware next and back buttons to move through my app. When a MessageBox is shown I would like to use the next and back buttons to click on Ok or Cancel on the dialog.

On my keydown event on my form my next and back buttons are registered as F6 and F7, I use the keydown event to check for these and run my Next and Back methods.

Is there a way to register a keydown event on a MessageBox? Or is there a way to set my application to recognize F6 and F7 as enter and Esc since a MessageBox will responded to those.

Comment: I would recomend you to use a custom mesagebox. The stock one is limited in many ways

Comment: You can't, but you can probably use `SendKeys` to mimic a user pressing `enter` or `escape` if `F6` or `F7` is pressed.

Comment: If you give the user a choice between touching the button on the message box and touching a custom button you added to your UI (and disabled by MesssageBox), then they will always, always, always hit the box button.  Ensuring that this button is big enough to hit with a fat thumb is a standard tweak in kiosk style apps.  If you also give them a keyboard then they'll use the arrow keys, the space bar to operate the button.